# How do I search for substrings in Bash?

Tags: bash, search, grep, string

I want to find out and display the total amount of TTT substrings found in the first 2,000 lines in the file.

I had been using **grep** until I tested it, and realized it does not identify substrings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the occurrence of 3 consecutive "T" characters in a file, you can do that with grep. What did you try that didn't work? And, if you only want to check the first 2,000 lines of the file, you could [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) the output of the [head](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/head.html) command into grep. E.g., `head -n 2000 somefile.txt | grep "TTT"` If you want a count of the lines in the file containing "TTT" you could use the following:

`head -n 2000 somefile.txt | grep -c "TTT"`

If some lines may have multiple occurrences and you want to count all occurrences rather than just the number of lines containing "TTT", then use the `-o` option for [grep](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/grep.html), which will display each occurrence on a separate line and then pipe the output into the [wc](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/wc.html) command, which will then display a count of all occurrences of "TTT" within the first 2000 lines of the file:

`head -n 2000 somefile.txt | grep -o "TTT" | wc -l`

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply! I had originally used the same command, however, when i tested grep with a much shorter file containing something like: JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT, it does not recognize the three substrings of TTT in TTTTT, it will highlight the first substring of 'TTT'TT and disregard the last two. :/

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

Normally, searching `TTT` (3 T's) in `TTTTTT` (6 T's) yield only 2 matches because the search for the next match is done right after the previous match is found.

I will try to illustrate:

```
TTTTTT
^ set starting position

TTTTTT
‾‾‾  found a match for TTT

TTTTTT
‾‾‾^ set next starting position

TTTTTT
   ‾‾‾  found a match for TTT

TTTTTT
      ^ end of stream
```

## Solution

If you want to consider `TTTTTT` as four instances of `TTT`, then I suggest you to match only a single character and then use [lookaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) to complete your matching pattern.

I will use a lookahead in my solution:

```sh
head -2000 file | /usr/gnu/bin/grep -P -o 'T(?=TT)' | wc -l
```

Explanations for the `grep` part:

- Use a `grep` that supports Perl regular expression to use lookahead; in my system I need to specify that to `/usr/gnu/bin/grep`
- `-P` to activate Perl regular expression mode
- `-o` to display each occurrence on a separate line to allow `wc -l` to count each matches
- `'T(?=TT)'` is a regular expression to match `T` which is followed by `TT` (using a lookahead); After finding a match, the regular expression engine will start at the *second* `T` to try to find the next match, allowing *that second* `T` to be a part of the next match if it conforms with the pattern.

## Example

Using your sample string from the comment:

- JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT

and processing it with the above regex:

```sh
echo 'JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT' | /usr/gnu/bin/grep -P --color=always 'T(?=TT)'
```

will produce:

- JKHFSD**T**TTJSDJH**TTT**TTKSJTII**T**TT (i.e. It will highlight 5 T's)

which means:

- it finds 5 matches :)

Illustration:

```
JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT
^ set starting position

JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT
      ‾^ found a match for T(?=TT) & set next starting position

JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT
              ‾^ found a match for T(?=TT) & set next starting position

JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT
               ‾^ found a match for T(?=TT) & set next starting position

JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT
                ‾^ found a match for T(?=TT) & set next starting position

JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT
                         ‾^ found a match for T(?=TT) & set next starting position

JKHFSDTTTJSDJHTTTTTKSJTIITTT
                            ^ end of stream
```